# How to Read XML Document containng same groups

Tags: c#, xml, attributes, xelement

I have one xml document and I want to read some data from that. The XML document is like below :-

[image]

**FYI -  This is the actual XML file syntax used in our application.**

Now I want to read the data from only one group say **group name="AutoSaveView"**. How would I do that ? Is there anyway that I can directly search the section containing group AutoSAve and then I can read the values of different labels from that.

I tried using XDocument the following way:-

```
    var doc = theFile.ToXML();
    var groups = doc.Element("resources").Element("group");
```

After that I am unable to get to the AutoSave element.

Comment: var autoSaveGroup = doc.Element("resources").Element("group").Where(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value == "AutoSaveView");

Comment: You can create a dictionary :            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("group")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.First());

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by implementing the code like below :-

```
      var xDocument = file.ToXML();
      var xElementResources = xDocument.Element("resources");

      if (xElementResources != null)
      {
        foreach (XElement element in xElementResources.Descendants("group"))
        {
         string groupName = element.Attribute("name")?.Value;
         if (groupName == "AutoSaveView")
         {
          var labelElements = element.Elements("label");

          foreach (var label in labelElements)
          {
             switch (label.FirstAttribute.Value)
             {
                 case "enableAutoSaveCheckEdit1":
                    this.RibbonControlApplicationButtonCaption = label.Value;
                    break;
             }
          }
        }
       }
     }
```